# Sum the records of subcategories and return the sum to the main category

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have this scenario. I have 2 tables:

- Table1 consists of Categories, Subcategories
- Table2 consists of Subcategories, Values
- Subcategories is unique Identifier and joins the two tables.

```
Categories: A, B, C etc.
Subcategories: aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc etc.
Each subcategory corresponds to a category. For example, aa, ab, ac correspond to category A. 
Values: 43, 10, 2    that is to say aa=43, ab=10, ac=2
```

What I am trying to do is to sum all the subcategories's values into the category.

That is to say:

```
Category=A              Sum=55

*Sum is 55 because I added all subcategories. (43+10+2)
```

- I do NOT want to have more than ONE ROW per category.
- I want to find the 20 best categories (not subcategories) according to the sum of values.
- However, I need to have subcategories in my new table, because I am finally going to join this new table (subquery) to an even bigger table and the only way to do so in through subcategories.

The problem is that if I include subcategories to the new table and then limit by 20 I will not have the top 20 categories but the 20 top subcategories. Any ideas?

Comment: It's appropriate to show what you've tried and why the results aren't what you want.  You'll likely want to aggregate using `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
  c.category, 
  sum(sb.subcategoryvalue)
FROM
  category c
  JOIN subcategory sb ON c.subid=sb.subid
GROUP BY c.category;
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: Subcategories with Values are in one table, and Subcategories and Categories are in another. The two tables join on Subcategories

Comment: Join the two then apply same above group by